# mysql LOOP not working

Tags: mysql, loops, procedure

I am using MySQL 5.6.10 through HeidiSQL. I am running hte following simple loop and come up with a syntax error :

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testif $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE testif()
    SET @number_title = 0;
    SET @max = (select count(distinct ctitle) FROM wb_hp_customers.hp_customers_final);
    BEGIN
    label1: LOOP
    IF (@number_title<@max) ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    @number_title = @number_title + 1;
LEAVE label1;
END LOOP label1;
    END $$  
    DELIMITER ;

    CALL testif();
```

The error I get is :

SQL Error (1064) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near label1: LOOP.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Few mistakes :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testif()
BEGIN
    SET @number_title = 0;
    SET @max1 = (select count(distinct ctitle) FROM wb_hp_customers.hp_customers_final);
    label1: LOOP
        IF (@number_title<@max1) THEN 
            ITERATE label1;
        END IF;
        SET @number_title := @number_title + 1;
    END LOOP;
END $$
```

This will work, but be careful for the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have a END LOOP label1; in your code.

Here is a better explanation of the LOOP protocol: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loop.html

Comment: IT still doesn't work. IT is a syntax error. 

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testif $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testif()
SET number_title = 0;
SET max= (select count(distinct ctitle) FROM table_final);
BEGIN
label1: LOOP
number_title = number_title + 1;
IF (number_title<max) ITERATE label1;
END IF;
LEAVE label1;
END LOOP label1;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;